# Google Federated Login (OpenID+Oauth) for Hosted Apps - changing end points?

Tags: python, openid, oauth, hybridauthprovider

I'm trying to integrate the Google Federated Login with a premier apps account, but I'm having some problems.

When I send the request to: `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud` with all the parameters (see below), I get back both a `request_token` and list of attributes asked for by `Attribute Exchange`. This is perfect, as we need the email via attribute exhange (AX) to store the user in our application database, and we need the request token for future `API requests to scopes` (ie: calendar, contacts, etc).

However, using that URL (herein referred to as the `endpoint`) doesn't keep the user signed in to their hosted apps (gmail, calendar, *et al*), which is a problem.

Changing the endpoint to `https://www.google.com/a/thedomain.com/o8/ud?be=o8` changes everything. I am automagically signed in to other google apps (gmail etc). However, using that endpoint, I only get the request token ***or*** the attributes via AX. Obviously thats not particularly Hybrid. Its very much one or the other.

Example request to the endpoint `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud`

```
parameters = {
    'openid.ns': 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0',
    'openid.claimed_id': 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select',
    'openid.identity': 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select',
    'openid.return_to':'http://our.domain.com/accounts/callback/',
    'openid.realm': 'http://our.domain.com/',
    'openid.assoc_handle': assoc_handle,
    'openid.mode': 'checkid_setup',

    'openid.ns.ext2': 'http://specs.openid.net/extensions/oauth/1.0',
    'openid.ext2.consumer': 'our.domain.com',
    'openid.ext2.scope': 'https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom',

    'openid.ns.ax':'http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0',
    'openid.ax.mode':'fetch_request',
    'openid.ax.required':'firstname,lastname,email',
    'openid.ax.type.firstname':'http://axschema.org/namePerson/first',
    'openid.ax.type.lastname':'http://axschema.org/namePerson/last',
    'openid.ax.type.email':'http://axschema.org/contact/email',     
}
return HttpResponseRedirect(end_point + '?' + urllib.urlencode(parameters))
```

(assoc_handle is previously set successfully by the openid initial request)

I've been struggling for days trying to get this Hybird approach working, fighting the most opaque error messages (`This page is invalid` ... thanks Google) and lack of consistent documentation. I've trawled every code sample I can to get to this point. Any help would be appreciated ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the record, posterity, and anyone else who might come asunder of this, I'll document the (ridiculous) answer.

Ultimately, the problem was calling:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(
    'https://www.google.com/a/thedomain.com/o8/ud?be=o8'
    + '?'
    + urllib.urlencode(parameters)
)
```

Can you spot it? Yeah, it was the explicit inclusion of the question mark that caused the problem. Two query strings never exist at once.